# Ruby on Rails "uninitialized constant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an application that tracks customers with quotes. Customer has many quotes and one belongs to one customer. I am trying to use a method that combines a first name and last name fields to produce a full name. My code is as follows.

Customer Model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotes
  def full_name
    "#{FName} #{LName}"
  end
end
```

Quotes form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Customer_Name %><br>
  <%= collection_select :Quote, :Customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :full_name, {}, {:multiple => true} %>
  </div>
```

When I try to create a new record, I am given an "uninitialized constant Customer::FName" error. Could someone please advise?

Comment: In rails anything that start with Uppercase or in Uppercase considered to be constant, FName and LName is referred as constants and constants should be defined before use

Comment: Thank you Pramod. This was my issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby anything identifier which begins with an uppercase letter is a constant.

```
irb(main):001:0> FOO = 'bar'
=> "bar"
irb(main):002:0> FOO = 'baz'
(irb):2: warning: already initialized constant FOO
(irb):1: warning: previous definition of FOO was here
=> "baz"
irb(main):003:0>
```

So class names which are constants are written in camelcase (`GhostWriter`) and attributes and methods are commonly written in `snake_case`.

Actual constants are written with all uppercase.

So to bring it all together

```
class Square # the class name Square is a constant
  SIDES = 4 # a constant

  attr_accessor :height 
  attr_accessor :width
  attr_accessor :background_color # attributes are written in snakecase

  def area 
    @height * width
  end

  def get_point # so are method names.
  end 
end
```

Comment: The issue was that I named my attributes with capitalization, which made them constants. Thank you for your help and prompt response. I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: There is nothing forcing you to write method names in snake case - Ruby only cares what the case of the first letter is and won't complain if you call it `firstName` or `fIrStNaMe`. However other programmers will since this is the accepted style.

Comment: There isn't even anything stopping you from writing methods in ALLCAPS or with the first letter capitalized.  See `Kernel#Float` as a single sample of many similar methods.